# Linq Find Uncommon Items In 2 List(Of String)

Tags: vb.net, linq

Using VB.net

I have two     List(Of String)

Here's how Im finding the common items between the two lists:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim lstOne As New List(Of String)() _
            From {"Jim", "Jack", "Kate", "Nope"}
        Dim lstTwo As New List(Of String)() _
            From {"Jack", "Nope", "Jim"}
        Dim lstNew As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing

        lstNew = lstOne.Intersect(lstTwo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

    End Sub
```

I want to use Linq to find the **uncommon items in these two lists.**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim lstOne As New List(Of String)() _
        From {"Jim", "Jack", "Kate", "Nope"}
    Dim lstTwo As New List(Of String)() _
        From {"Jack", "Nope", "Jim"}
    Dim lstNew As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing

    lstNew = lstOne.Intersect(lstTwo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

    Dim uncommon As IEnumerable(Of String) = lstOne.Union(lstTwo).Except(lstNew, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

    For Each element As String In uncommon
        Console.WriteLine(element)
    Next

End Sub
```

Output:

```
Kate
```

Answer (score 2):

To stick within pure LINQ, you can use `Except`:

```
Dim inOneNotTwo As IEnumerable(Of String) = lstOne.Except(lstNew)
Dim inTwoNotOne As IEnumerable(Of String) = lstTwo.Except(lstNew)
```

Alternatively, you could use `HashSet(Of T)` and [`SymmetricExceptWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848):

```
Dim strings As HashSet(Of String) = new HashSet(Of String)(lstOne)
strings.SymmetricExceptWith(lstTwo)
```